# How to check if table exists in MySql db?

Tags: mysql, database, vb6, odbc, ado

I have a VB6 application and I want to check if a table exists within a MySQL database on phpmyadmin. In reality the table is actually a view however it should act exactly as it's own table.

The code I currently have constantly returns false?

I think my problem might have to do with the variable cnDataStoreToVerify because when I try to print its Contents it only contains:
"Provider=MSDASQL.1;" ?

Help would be much appreciated!

```
Public Function TableExists(cnDataStoreToVerify As ADODB.Connection, strTableName as String) As Boolean

 Dim recTemp As ADODB.Recordset
 Set recTemp = cnDataStoreToVerify.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, Array(Empty, Empty, StrTableName, Empty)) 

 If Not recTemp.EOF Then
   TableExists = True 
 End If

 Exit_TableExists: 
 m_oADOUtils.CloseRecordsetADO recTemp

End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried using [ADOX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? I've only used it with (Microsoft Jet) OLEDB, and I don't have a MySQL db readily available to test, you could be lucky enough that checking for table existence might be supported with the... Wait, which driver/connector are you using on the MSDASQL provider for MySQL?

Comment: Otherwise, can you execute SQL on the connection ? And does your user have read access to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`? Because you could execute `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table_name';` and check the recordset for results, i.e. 1 result  = table exists, no result = table not found.

Comment: Or, 3rd option (best one yet): the [SHOW TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html) statement.

Comment: Sorry, I just read it was for a view (I don't mean to spam the question with comments...)  Please substitute `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` with [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views-table.html) and `SHOW TABLES` with [`SHOW CREATE VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-view.html) in the previous 2 comments. Both require the [SHOW VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-view) privilege.

Comment: I am using the MySQL odbc driver : with the following connection string http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/. I think this statement may work for a MySQL db but the cnDataStoreToVerify containts only Provider=MSDASQL.1; which isn't the proper connection string format?